# Angular use a reg exec validator to stop input of a MatInput-field but stay editable

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create an editable MatInput-field, which stop the possibility to add more numbers, when it hits a certain point, maximum of 6 numbers before or 2 numbers after the comma.
My Validator looks like this:

```
    public static floatingAmount(c: FormControl) {
    let reg = /^[0-9]{1,6}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$/;
    let OK = reg.exec(c.value);
    if (!OK) {
        return null;
    } else {
        console.log(c.value);
        return { floatingAmount: true };
    }
}
```

In the console I see, that the validator works perfectly and only throw numbers, when it have a max of 6 numbers. When it reaches two numbers after the comma, it stops too.
Now I want to bring this to my input field, but here I stucks.
What I found out till here is I can give the InputField a maximum character and then it is still editable, but you cant put MORE numbers.
Is there a way to use the Validator as a dynamic maxlength attribute for the input field?

Comment: I think I will implement this with a custom directive with hostListener